# How to measure Na/K channel activation at the membrane level?

Tags: biophysics, electrophysiology, action-potential, electrocardiography, signalling

Assume that there are two different signals occurring on the ECG - during depolarization and repolarization in the standard ECG. 
I was advised not to use the standard ECG in measuring the exact electrical events during:

- stages 0-2
- 3-4

We can get data about the electric activity of neurons in vivo in Fig. 1 where some data about the electric activity of neurons is present.
So my thought is that a similar technique could probably work with cardiomyocytes.

Fig. 1 Example of measurement for electric activity of neurons in vivo

[image]

I estimate that there is about 18% uncertainty when using the standard ECG because of the peak in the stage 1 (Gibbs phenomenon) and those two complete different phases.

Comment: This is probably not possible *in vivo*, but there are various methods (voltage clamping, channel blockers) that you can use *in vitro* with individual cells and perhaps correlate the results with the aggregate activity of a larger piece of heart muscle.

Comment: @jonsca I found that we can get data about the electric activity of neurons in vivo. So probably the same technique has been used with cardiomyocytes.

Comment: @Masi Neurons are easier because they aren't moving that much.

Comment: @NickSandor Can you please make your comment an answer and support it with evidence and/or sources. It is very interesting, but true. Can you say how much neurons and cardiomyocytes move, please. - - I am really interested in on any estimates about the topic because I have overlooked it for long time. - - Can you please state what you expect to be seen in cardiomyocyte activity? What is their metric in time-frequency plane or time-potential plane? I get mostly cloudy areas but different from neuron areas when studying spectrograms and other distributions.

Comment: I searched Pubmed for cardiomyocyte+"patch clamp", and read the first ~10 abstracts. Everyone measures plated cells. At best, these cells came from from hearts freshly minced in collagenase / EDTA. See PMIDs 27364017, 27076034, 26142302, 26241168, 26378152, to mention the most recent search results.

Comment: @NickSandor Please, see my new question here about the topic http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/50630/86 - - Why are they measuring exactly plated cells?