# How much Cardiomyocyte Move in Relation to its Neurons?

Tags: cardiology, biophysics, movement, signalling, electromuscular

I am trying to estimate how much cardiomyocyte and its things (mitochondria) move in relation to neurons

1. Movement of neurons ([1](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/19728/86))
2. **Movement of cardiomyocytes**
3. **Movement of cardiomyocytes' mitochondrias** ([2](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23675354))
4. ...
5. Movement of stem cells - I think we can ignore this one

Motivation: some imaging projects have focused on the neurons etc ECG/... because they move relatively little in comparison to cardiomyocytes and their organelles; my interest is in the electromuscular view and I would like to understand how the movement of cardiomyocytes and their mitochondrias could be adjusted/calibrated in the time-frequency (t-f) data (spectrogram/...) of cardiomyocytes

### Pseudocode

Simplistic view about including the effect of cytoarchitecture of organelles on the dynamics/movements based on statistics and probabilistic approaches

```
function getMitochondriaDynamics2D(signal2D, edges, Cytoarchitecture):
signal2D=$1;
edgesN=size($2,2); 
organelles=[neurons, cardiomyocyte_minus_mitochondia, mitochondria, ...]; % given
organelles.cytoarchitecture = $3; % probabilistic values in Statistics
organelles.dynamics = zeros(1,edgesN-1); % preallocation 

% Limit dynamics by cytoarchitectural restrictions
for organelle in organelles
    % include here systemic effects on organelles but Ignored here
    % etc Age, Smoking, ... 

    % Let's loop local changes
    for edge in organelles.dynamics
        organelle.dynamics(edge) = organelle.dynamics(edge) .* ...
            organelle.cytoarchitecture(edge); 
    end
end   

return signal2D .*organelle(mitochondria).dynamics; 

end

%% TODO here  
function analysisMitochondriaDynamics2D(dynamics2D)
    ... 
end
```

To find those probabilistic values

- Embryology but I am weak here
- databases and/or publications - which?

### Biochemistry

I do not understand how much this should be considered here, but it could help to get any model

- Atrial cardiomyocyte calcium signalling
- mobility of the delayed-rectifer K+ channel Kv2.1 ([3](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17965280))

Useful keywoards

- cardiomyocyte adult mobility

### Hypothesis and Math/Physics/Bio

Hypothetical View of t-f data (2D) in cardiomyocytes: regular points separated by steady-gel-like areas - - seems to artifact of the movement

Physics about characterizing such areas:

- ... [ which mathematical methods ] ...

### Sources

There are much studies in Embryology about cardiomyocytes and their movement, but I cannot understand their relation in the topic

1. Piquereau, [Mitochondrial dynamics in the adult cardiomyocytes: which roles for a highly specialized cell?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23675354), 2013
2. [How to measure Na/K channel activation at the membrane level?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/19728/86)
3. [Localization and mobility of the delayed-rectifer K+ channel Kv2.1 in adult cardiomyocytes.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17965280)
4. [Mitochondrial dynamics in the adult cardiomyocytes: which roles for a highly specialized cell?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23675354)
5. PubMed with `cardiomyocyte+"patch clamp"`, about measuring plated cells which are from hearts freshly minced in collagenase / EDTA. See PMIDs 27364017, 27076034, 26142302, 26241168, 26378152, ... [NickSandor]

Useful keywords

- adult cardiomyocyte
- possibly: Atrial cardiomyocyte calcium signalling
- Mitochondrial dynamics
- cytoarchitecture restrictions dynamics